# Get request Content-Length on kuzzle search javascript-sdk

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, kuzzle

i wondering how can i get the Content-Length size when i call `kuzzle.document.search`.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by Content-Length size? Do you want to get the total number of documents available?

Comment: No, i just want how many Mb i downloaded with the search result. So i can show, for example: 1,23Mb fetched

Comment: Ok I see, there is no way to do that for now except by directly calling the HTTP API and reading the "Content-Length" header. If you can briefly explain your use case I will propose this feature in our next product workshop

Comment: I need it to create a sort of offline mode where the user download multimedia, maps and data. With async calls i can show how many mb i m downloading as well.

Comment: Ok I see. I will suggest this feature in our product workshop and I will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the content of the `Content-Length` header is not directly available through the Javascript SDK.

You can either send a raw HTTP request to Kuzzle to get this header by yourself or you can approximately compute the total size of the response by hand:

```
let result = await sdk.document.search(...);
const contentLength = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(result._response)).byteLength;
```

As I say in the comment, I will suggest this feature in our product workshop. I will keep you informed.